# Populate Select element with LINQ and WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Here is my select list.

```
<div class="field">
    <select name="position" id="position" class="grayed" onclick="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" class="disabled">Applicant's position</option>
    </select>
    <div id="arrow-select"></div>
    <svg id="arrow-select-svg"></svg>
    <span class="entypo-book icon"></span>
    <span class="slick-tip left">Choose Position</span>
</div>
```

Here is my LINQ:

```
from v in Jobs
select new
{
    ID = v.Id,
    Title = v.Title
}
```

How do I combine the two so the select list is populated with what is returned from the LINQ query?

It has to be a select element not the asp:dropdown.

Comment: Mind if I ask why not an asp:dropdownlist?

Comment: @Mark the css im using isn't asp:dropdown friendly been fighting it and gave up on trying to convert it to the asp:dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `runat="server"` into your `select` html tag

In your code behind, use the **ID** of your `select`:

```
var data = from v in Jobs
           select new
           {
              ID = v.Id,
              Title = v.Title
           };

position.DataSource = data.ToList();
position.DataTextField = "Title";
position.DataValueField = "ID";
position.DataBind();

position.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Applicant's position", ""));
```

Comment: This errors out on the DataBind().  An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code  We use Entity and LINQ in other places, not sure what would be causing this.

Comment: We came to that conclusion about the same time I think.  That gets me a bit further, no errors.  But now my select list has this in it { ID = 5, Title = Title }

Comment: Try configuring it with `DataTextField` and `DataValueField`

Comment: Bah!  I should have known that.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: One more question Justin.  This select box doesn't have the `appenddatabounditems` options.  How can I include my default option above that says "Applicant's Position" ?

Comment: Simply add `position.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Applicant's position", ""));` after your binding